# HTML content displayed as pure string instead of getting rendered as a website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, express

Hello I am getting started with implementing APIs in my project to build a Weather reporting project.This is my .js script.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    var city = req.body.cityName;
    var url =
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=13c938e16426e3aa234d67fc162bf227&q=" +
        city +
        "";
    https.get(url, function (response) {
        response.on("data", function (data) {
            const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
            var temp = weatherData.main.temp;
            var weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;
            var iconUrl =
                "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" +
                weatherData.weather[0].icon +
                "@2x.png";

            res.write("<img src=" + iconUrl + ">");
            res.write(
                "<h1>the weather in " + city + " is = " + weatherDescription + "</h1>"
            );

            res.write("<h1>the temprature in your area is " + temp + " </h1>");

            res.send();
          
        });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("the server has started at port 3000");
});
```

Now I get the response of the post request as

```
<img src=https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03n@2x.png><h1>the weather in Gorakhpur is = scattered clouds</h1><h1>the temperature in your area is 304.93 </h1>   //Gorakhpur is name of city (:
```

this is as a string but i want it yo render it like a website.

Instead, when I do respond in this order the html is **rendered** just fine.

```
            res.write(
            "<h1>the weather in " + city + " is = " + weatherDescription + "</h1>"
            );

            res.write("<h1>the temprature in your area is " + temp + " </h1>");

            res.write("<img src=" + iconUrl + ">");
            res.send(); 

            //Here I changed the order of image tag
```

can you explain the reason behind it??

Comment: You have a wrong syntax for your html, thtt could be the cause. You are not closing the `img` tag, the `src` param should be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: can u explain how to do that?? since if i try to enclose the src with double quotes it will just open and close the string

Comment: @Pipe: the `<img>` tag doesn't need to be closed in HTML (only in XML/XHTML), and the `src` attribute doesn't need to be quoted unless it contains white-space and it's valid to quote - if you wish to do so - with *either* `src="<URI>"` or `src='<URI>'`. As for your questions to the OP, "*[is s/he] aware what HTML is?*" - that simply appears rude, but that's my inference and not, necessarily, your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with this line,

```
res.write("<img src=" + iconUrl + ">");
```

image tag in html has qoutes around src link. You html passing the src without qoutes. you can use single and double qoutes here.

```
res.write('<img src="' + iconUrl + '">');
```